# Ignore XML tags within HTML page

Tags: html, xml

I have few XML documents that needs to be displayed on a page but the content is getting parsed.

I want the whole content to be displayed as it is.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/engrLgar/)

Comment: It sounds like you want to escape all the tags into entities and wrap it in `<pre>` tags

Answer (score 0):

As James says:

> escape all the tags into entities and wrap it in `<pre>` tags

Write it as:

```
<pre>
    <lt;dependency>
        <lt;groupId>com.sun.jersey<lt;/groupId>
        <lt;artifactId>jersey-server<lt;/artifactId>
        <lt;version>1.8<lt;/version>
    <lt;/dependency>
</pre>
```